# Why is Rules reacting on Commerce Events multiple times and out of order?

Tags: commerce, rules

I am having lots of problems with my site because Rules is evaluating Events multiple times, and out of order.

For example, the debug log shows that when I add a product to cart, Rules reacts as follows:

`Calculating the sell price of a product` <- for internal processing, ok.
`Calculating the sell price of a product` <- why twice?
`Before saving a commerce line item`
`Apply a fee to a given order` <- why now?
`After updating an existing commerce order` <- but it didn't update; no fee added?
`After adding a product to the cart`
`Calculating the sell price of a product` <- for display, ok.
`Apply a fee to a given order` <- why now? and why again?
`Select available payment methods for an order` <- why now?

Would like to know if there is a way to debug deeper than the log; i.e. find out exactly when each rule evaluation was called ...

Somebody please help, this is making it impossible to work!

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I had upgraded to PayPal WPP, but also left PayPal Express Checkout enabled.

This caused EC to not display where it normally does, i.e. on every page starting with the cart, but to only display on the Review page where other payment methods can be selected. However, the Rules events for EC were evaluated in their normal place in the process.

Thus the Events were being evaluated even though they had apparently not occurred.

The multiple evaluations of the Event "Calculating the price of a product" is normal.